# Convert ut8 to non utf8 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using this to create username based on name. Name needs to be utf8 but username does not. How could I convert utf8 to non utf8?

```
public static function createUsername ($name, $count = 0) {
        $username = implode('.', explode(' ', strtolower($name)));

        if ($count > 0) {
            $username = $username . $count;
        }

        if (count(self::where('username', $username)->get()) > 0) {
            self::createUsername($name, $count++);
        }

        return $username;
    }
```

Comment: You could try [utf8_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) or [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: First one returned ? instead of letter and second  one error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Str.html) provides a function for converting utf-8 strings into ASCCI.

Str::ascii($string)

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this as the performance gain is likely not all too great. See [Does using ASCII/Latin Charset speed up the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488429/does-using-ascii-latin-charset-speed-up-the-database)

Comment: Well I got problem with nuxt and laravel encoding ut8 strings. Username is used by get method from url, so it makes so ugly string that doesn't work in laravel. I didn't want to go through nuxt crap since a lot of their things has problems. God kill me why I tried nuxt instead of react on angular....

Comment: if you're planning on using the stringsas part of a query, I'd take a look at urlencode()/urldevcode() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php
It may be what you're looking for instead.